# Mathematical Mechanics - Friction Question (weight is laid upon an inclined plane)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

A weight W is laid upon a rough plane [µ=1/(sqrrt3)] inclined at 45 degrees to the horizon. It is connected by a string passing through a smooth ring A, at the top of the plane, with a weight P hanging vertically. If W=3P, show that if θ is the greatest possible inclination of the string AW to the line of greatest slope of the plane, then prove that: cosθ=(2 * sqrrt2)/3

Find also the direction in which W would commence to move.

I can not understand the diagram in the given picture that the person made. I think the diagram is wrong. If it is correct, i would like to know the correct diagram and solution.

[click here for diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el5bf.png)

Comment: This seems more apppropriate for Physics SE

Comment: The diagram is a mess, Where is W on it? Sorry, but I don't think anyone can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

To get the answer, you must be looking for the maximum angle for which all forces are in balance (no motion) which makes a bit of a mockery of the second question.

The Normal force will have magnitude $\frac w{\sqrt 2}$

So max magnitude for friction is $|F_{fr}|^{max}= \frac{\mu W }{\sqrt 2} $
The component of  gravity parallel to the inclined plane has magnitude $\frac W {\sqrt 2}$
It is directed down the plane at an angle $\theta$ to the Tension vector.

Again assuming that the system is in equilibrium the magnitude of the Tension vector must be $|\vec T|=P$

Thee result is obtained by writing out cosine law for the magnitude of the frictional force and setting that to its maximum value.
i.e.

$$ \frac{\mu ^2 W^2}2 = P^2 + \frac {W^2}2 -2 \frac{PW}{\sqrt 2} \cos(\theta)$$

plug in the values for $\mu$ and $\frac WP$ and you should get the desired result.